# Mouse cursor BGE low resolution

Tags: game-engine

I divided my display size by 4 for my window having 420x360 resolution, this is what I need for my game, **but** while in fullscreen mode the cursor is stuck in the area of window instead of extending over the display area. This makes it impossible to select anything outside the initial window box. Doubling the resolution doesn't create this issue though, I wonder how to fix this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is usefull, I used a script to track the mouse and move an object which acts as a cursor independently.

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
mouse = cont.sensors['Mouse']
cursor = cont.owner

width = bge.render.getWindowWidth()
height = bge.render.getWindowHeight()

mousex =  float(mouse.position[0])
mousey =  float(mouse.position[1])
x = (mousex  / (width/2))  -0.75426
y = (-mousey / height) +0.35371

cont.owner.worldPosition = ((x), (y), (0.0))
```